# How can you set the max.message.bytes of a state store changelog topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams application with messages up to 10MiB. I want to persist these messages in a state store, but Kafka Streams fails to produce to the internal changelog topic:

```
2017-11-17 08:36:19,792 ERROR RecordCollectorImpl - task [4_5] Error sending record to topic appid-statestorename-state-store-changelog. No more offsets will be recorded for this task and the exception will eventually be thrown
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The request included a message larger than the max message size the server will accept.
2017-11-17 08:36:20,583 ERROR StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Failed while executing StreamTask 4_5 due to flush state:
```

By adding some logging, it looks like the default `max.message.bytes` setting of an internal topic is 1MiB.

The default `max.message.bytes` for the cluster is set to 50MiB.

**Is it possible to tweak the configuration of internal topics of Kafka Streams applications?**

---

A work-around is to start the streams application, let it create the topics, and afterwards alter the topic config. But this feels like a dirty hack.

```
./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper ... \
      --alter --topic appid-statestorename-state-store-changelog \
      --config max.message.bytes=10485760
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to change this configuration programmatically. As a possible workaround you can precreate all topics with custom parameters and then start your app.

Comment: It's not possible atm to specify custom properties for internal topic.It's a know issue and will be fixed for sure in the future. Feel free to create a JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1?jql=project%20%3D%20KAFKA -- thus your workaround is correct. Note, you can also get the names of changelog topics via `Topology#describe()` (or `KafkaStreams#toString()` -- old API)

Comment: Thanks guys for the swift responses. 
We maintain our topic creation/configuration using Ansible, so currently I prefer to create the topics upfront instead of syncing app deployment and topic config.

Comment: Ticket created: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6248

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka `1.0` allows to specify custom topic properties for internal topics via `StreamsConfig`.

You prefix those configs with `"topic."` and can use any configs as defined in `TopicConfig`.

See the original KIP for more details:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-173%3A+Add+prefix+to+StreamsConfig+to+enable+setting+default+internal+topic+configs